# Problems using Borland C++ compiler (version 5.5)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, borland-c++

Declaration:

```
namespace a {
    namespace b {
        class Classe {
           public:
         Classe();
        };
    }
}
```

Definition:

```
#include "sample.h"

namespace a {
     b::Classe::Classe(){}
}
```

But with this definition I got this error:

> Error E2038 .\sample.cpp 4: Cannot
>   declare or define
>   'b::Classe::Classe()' here

Everything works fine when changing source to:

```
#include "sample.h"

namespace a {
     namespace b {
          Classe::Classe(){}
     }
}
```

How can I compile without change the whole code?

It's not my choice. In fact, I am a developer in a Linux environment, and I never thought that I would develop on Windows again. It's for a specific customer that only works with the Borland C++ compiler.

I found [this wiki page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2038_Cannot_declare_or_define_%27identifier%27_here:_wrong_namespace_%28C++%29) from Embarcadero. It doesn't help much.

---

I give up. I'm doing what Remy said.

Comment: You've given `Classe::Classe` a body in the class definition. I assume it was meant to be only a declaration?

Comment: Borland C++ isn't the most compliant compiler. It has a lot of quirks. This might be one of those!

Comment: @Hans Passant: You can't imagine how I would like to change from Borland C++ to M$, MinGW compilers.

Comment: Well, you'd better double the quote next time.

Comment: Hans Passant and others.  I saw a lot of topics where people at first instead of help said that it's old-old compiler. but sometimes we need it, how do   you think can one easy compile driver for lpt or com port using visual studio , g++   for  DOS?  or would you say that it better to move from DOS to windows? yeah,it's better. but it isn't so easy. especially when you have a little time and there no place to figure out how to work with ports from protection mode , it's much harder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the namespace block in the .cpp file, and just qualify the entire constructor:

```
#include "sample.h"

a::b::Classe::Classe(){}
```

Comment: My problem is that I have to many classes to apply this change. I would like to do this only if there is no workaround.

Comment: how many files do you have ? You could use this regex to replace your code  as remy sayd ([\w_]*::[\w_]*::[\w_]*\\()  / new_part::$1

Comment: Ok, I can do this, but as I said, I would like to do this only if there is no workaround. There is no problem on replacing, I could use `sed`for example. Thanks.

Comment: @coel what about using a more updated version of borland like C++ Builder 2006-2007? Many bugs like this have been fixed since then.

Comment: @Victor Nope, I tested on current C++Builder XE (trial version) :/. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all the declarations are in one block, you could try changing `namespace b { }` to `struct b { };`.